# .htaccess directory redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, directory, dns

Our website's files are located at **domain1.com/directory** - I've just bought a new domain (**domain2.com**) and would like it to look as if the files are coming from the new domain, but actually pull content from **domain1.com/directory**

Can you please help me with the necessary code for the .htaccess file in the root directory of **domain1.com** so that **domain2.com** points to **domain1.com/directory**?

Comment: Is `DOCUMENT_ROOT` same for both domains or different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Adriano. In the end I used a combination of a CNAME DNS entry to point to the original domain and made the new domain an 'Add-on Domain' in the original domain's cPanel. All is working a-ok now.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain2.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/directory/$1 [r=307,nc]
```